# Zeppelin Notebook Storage in local Git repository

Tags: git, apache-zeppelin

I have followed the instructors for setting up Zeppelin Notebook Storage in local Git repository here:

https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT/storage/storage.html#Git

But i am still unclear about how i can store versions of the notebooks in Git. Has anyone else tried this and what was your experience?

Comment: The features are still extremely limited (0.7.0-SNAPSHOT).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the link you provided, it look's like the xml file you're working with should have a commented block that resembles the following:

```
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.notebook.storage</name>
  <value>org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo</value>
  <description>notebook persistence layer implementation</description>
</property>
```

Maybe it's commented out somehow, like maybe there is `!--` or some other strange characters within the `<property>` tag that you can remove in order to enable the block and git access.

Comment: Thanks mkrufky, I think i figured it out. I did all of the above but when you look in the GitNotebookRepo.java file you find the following comment <!-- language: lang-js --> NotebookRepo that hosts all the notebook FS in a single Git repo
 *
 * This impl intended to be simple and straightforward:
 *   - does not handle branches
 *   - only basic local git file repo, no remote Github push\pull yet -->

Comment: With my 0.7.2 installation, I only had to install git (on Debian with apt) and it worked then out of the box since the Git-Option in the xml file was already activated. Now it works without flaws.